Access ServiceM8 Recurring Jobs via API
A client of mine would like to check all his recurring jobs scheduled by the "Recurring Jobs + Reminders" add-on. I tested it but found that until they are activated, they don't appear in Job / Job Activity APIs. Is there a way to retrieve them before they are activated?

